# Deleting rows depending on the combobox value

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, userform

I want to have a userform populate when the macro is run. The userform has a combobox that I would like all the values form Sheet("Sheet1").Range column A be the list. If the user selects a value that is in that range, I would like the code to delete the whole row where the value is. Example: If the user selects John and John is in Column A of the Sheet1, once the user submits the userform the whole row with John is deleted.

I also have another scenario, where I would like only up until Column M be deleted. After submitting the userform Columns A:N are deleted but the columns M and on stay as is.

The code I have tried is below.

```
Private sub commandbutton1_Click()
Dim smessage = "are you sure you want to delete the Row?"
if Msgbox(smessage, vbQuestion + vbYesNo,_ "Confirm 
Delete") = vbYes Then 
Dim LastRow as long, i as Long

LastRow = Columns(1).Find("*",SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

For i = LastRow To 1 Step -1
If Cells(i,"A") = Combobox1.Text Then 
Rows(i).delete
End If 
Next
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `Range("A" & i & ":M" & i).Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp`? Assuming you mixed up `M` and `N` in your question.

Comment: @BigBen thanks for the quick reply. I will add that to the scenario. The code i have does not seem to do the basics of deleting the row that has the value of the combobox. Do you see anything in my code that would cause this not to work?

Comment: For starters I would qualify the `Worksheet` that the `Columns` and `Cells` and `Rows` are on.

Comment: You show code you tried but don't say anything about what happens when you run it.

Comment: Add `Debug.Print i, """" & Cells(i,"A") & """", """" & Combobox1.Text & """"` just below the For loop (above the If) and run it, check if the Loop really got executed. Look at the Immediate Window to see the values.

Comment: @PatricK works great when I run it. Now if I would like the range to delete from Column A:N how would I adjust the code. Instead of Rows.(I).Delete would it be something like Rows(I).Range("A:N").delete

Comment: @Patrick Ok works great but because the macro is on a different worksheet then where I would like the row deleted it does not delete. I tried placing with Worksheets.... before the userform runs, no luck at this point. Do you know what I should add to have the macro run on another sheet?

Comment: Refer to BigBen's comment about A:N delete. To apply changes to different worksheet, create a Worksheet variable and set it to the worksheet to apply on. `Dim oWS as Worksheet : Set oWS = Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Index or Name")`, then use `oWS.Columns...`, `oWS.Cells...`.